# Conversation Scope in Resource Handler in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, jboss7.x

I have a Resource Handler that needs to access lower level beans that work in conversation scope. Our application allows multiple login sessions on different browser tabs working within the same browser session by keeping the login details at this scope - so a database access (my Resource Handler) needs the login for the Conversation that referenced it.

I've tried just expecting it to work, even using ExternalContext.encodeRedirectUrl() to try to make Faces include whatever it needs.

I've tried explicitly putting the ?cid parameter onto my request path so I am accessing

```
/myapp/javax.faces.resource/thumbnail_3963075518712822225212162218.png.xhtml?ln=com.myapp.attachment&cid=1
```

No Conversation appears in the Resource Handler.

Further if I try to test for this using Conversation.isTransient() I get a

```
javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: Conversation Context not active when method called on conversation Transient conversation
```

(Yet I thought Conversation is always meant to be active, and the stack trace for the above *does* include the org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter!

I'm hoping this is not to do with the bug https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBSEAM-3689 - for which the workaround is "Do not use conversations!"

Is there better?

Thanks
 - Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Seam Faces](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/FacesModule) and see if you can get things to work the way you want. JSF has next to no compatibility with CDI in the JSF 2.0 and 2.1 specs. We're working hard with the lead for JSF to make it better for JSF 2.2, sorry for any inconveniences.

Comment: We'd tried that and found it slowed us down a lot. Perhaps another problem. We have some pretty huge jars - autogenerated service stubs and DTOs for our legacy application server totalling some thousands of classes. They don't have beans.xml. We use a CDI extension to hand register the service interfaces. We still found a huge slowdown when we enabled Seam Faces. (This in JBoss 7.0.1)  
My thoughts at the moment are to code around the problem, try to avoid it. I have a user and password equivalent at Session level. I can encode the partition (3rd part of logon) in the request.

Comment: The slowness issue is interesting, would you mind creating a JIRA for us with as much information as you can give us?

Comment: I would have to see what I can get - setting up an environment where I can re-enable it.

Comment: Things are on hold at the moment. We've been instructed from On High (the company that bought us out a little while ago) to dramatically change direction - so future questions coming from here are likely to be about Javascript and JAX-RS!

Answer (score 0):

Mad idea - write an XHTML page with a Restore View event handler that manually renders the resource and calls Complete() on the FacesContext. Ugh! But XHTML pages do get conversations.

Answer (score 0):

I have done what is perhaps suggested in the bug report. I've found a way of solving the problem not using Conversation Scope. In my case I have a ThreadLocal that, if present, provides alternate information to the component that access Conversation Scoped data.

Comment: *** WARNING ***   Servers are now free to use async techniques and non-blocking IO to share a server thread amongst multiple requests. The use of ThreadLocal would be risky in such a situation. I'll investigate RequestScope instead and hope that is available for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  [Apache Myfaces CODI](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/),

Conversation management is superb with their extensions